# UI to call Google Apps Script function from Gmail?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function (and supporting functions) that reads from my Gmail account, parses the contents of the mails to find PayPal payment information, and write that information to a Google spreadsheet. It works perfectly. What I don't know is how the user can invoke this function. Gmail lacks an Add-ons menu or an object model to program against it. So how can my Gmail users invoke the function?

Comment: you could publish the script as a web-app and the users just need to be given the URL of the published webapp to invoke it. They'll have to sign-in with their gmail credentials.

Comment: Just what I needed to know. Thank you, Sujay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the script is attached to a spreadsheet then they can just run it from that. Otherwise, you can deploy it as a web app and have an interface separate from Gmail. You can embed it into a Google Site as well.

I have a script that gets each **message** (not conversation) from a specified timeframe and writes the received date, sender, recipient, message title into a spreadsheet. The user calls this script from a web interface. To allow for extra information (such as instructions and hidden documentation for future maintainers) I embed it into a Google Site. I did that because the script creates new spreadsheets each time, so if it's the same on your end, that's what I would recommend doing.

You can create an HTML file in the script editor and use

```
function doGet(e) {
  var htmlPage = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index.html')
  return htmlPage
}
```

to display have the web page displayed.

Comment: Perfect, Vytautas! I wasn't sure if there was a secret Add-on mechanism in Gmail I was missing or what.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom spreadsheet function and invoke it manually by typing the function name in a spreadsheet cell. This works on both desktops and mobiles.

For instance, if the code is:

```
function getTransaction() {
  // Your code here
}
```

You can go to the spreadsheet, and enter =getTransaction() in the cell to execute the function.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but an awesome arrow in the quiver. This will definitely be helpful someday. Thank you, Amit.